# How to insert batch data with CoreData?

Tags: ios, core-data

My situation is more than 200 objects would come to me one by one per second through a callback function,  obviously I cannot save a entity every single time in this callback function, that will cause UI suspend, so my question is how to insert batch data with core data?

### ------------------------------------------------------------

Edit:

thanks, guys, I re-edit my code like this, and there are some issues, 
 if I receive "1", "2", "3"...from the callback function frequently, my tableview often shows "1", "3", "2"... , they are in wrong order.  if anything wrong, plz let me know.

in AppDelegate.m file:

```
    - (NSManagedObjectContext *)mainManagedObjectContext {     
        if (_ mainManagedObjectContext != nil) {
            return _managedObjectContext;
        }

        _mainManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        _mainManagedObjectContext.parentContext = [self rootManagedObjectContext];
        return _mainManagedObjectContext;
    }

    - (NSManagedObjectContext*)rootManagedObjectContext {

        if (_rootManagedObjectContext != nil) {
            return _rootManagedObjectContext;
        }

        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
        if (!coordinator) {
            return nil;
        }


        _rootManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_rootManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
        return _rootManagedObjectContext;
    }
```

in the callback function I do this, I tried to replace `_mainManagedObjectContext`
with `_rootContext` or `_workContext`int callback function, but data never show on the tableview;

```
- (void)saveChatMessage:(ChatMessage*)msg userInfo:(UserInfo*)user chatType:(ChatType)chatType receiverID:(long long)receiverID receiverName:(NSString*)receiverName
{

        ChatObject *chatObject = [NSEntityDescription
                                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ChatObject"
                                  inManagedObjectContext: _mainManagedObjectContext];

        chatObject.receiveTime = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[NSDate date].timeIntervalSince1970];
        chatObject.text = msg.text;
        chatObject.richText = msg.richText;
        chatObject.senderID = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:user.userID];
        chatObject.senderName = user.userName;
        chatObject.chatType = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:chatType];
        chatObject.isFromHost = [NSNumber numberWithBool:user.isOrganizer];
        chatObject.receiverID = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:receiverID];
        chatObject.receiverName = receiverName;


        NSError *error;
        if (![_workerContext save:&error]) {

        }

        if (![_rootContext save:&error]) {

        }

}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"ChatObject" inManagedObjectContext:_mainManagedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"receiveTime" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];


    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:_mainManagedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

Comment: have u tried using GCD

Comment: @vaibby yep, I've tried, but data in the tableview cannot display correctly.

Comment: I don't understand ".. would come to me one by one per second ...". Where do the objects come from? From the network? From the bundle?

Comment: @DanielRinser From the network,it's an internet meeting,if one of the members send a text, we can receive it from a callback function, if there are many enough people in the meeting, and everyone send a text,this callback function will be called very frequently.I try to save the text and show it on a tableview.

Comment: Ok, and you get 200(!) individual such requests per *second*?

Comment: Go through this website, [link](http://floriankugler.com/2013/04/29/concurrent-core-data-stack-performance-shootout/). Create a worker context (NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType)that does work of inserting data from NSData (downloaded from internet).  An intermediate main context(NSMainQueueConcurrencyType) which handles interaction (fetching/ updating) from UI and a master Context (NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType) that interact directly with NSPersistentStoreCoordinator). This will always keep you main context in sync with latest data.

Comment: @Alok I re-eidt my code, plz have a look, if i go wrong, let me know.

Comment: @DanielRinser if many enough members send text at the same time, I will.

Comment: @Gaojin Hsu, you have not shown all the code including you UITableView  implementations as well as NSFetchedResultController delegate implementation.  Also you need to execute performFetch on you NSfetchResultController, i.e in -viewDidLoad method ` //execute fetch request
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultController]performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Cannot fetch error is %@", error);
        abort();
    }
` . When you are saving that much data, insert it in worker Context, performBlock save on worker context , it will be available to main context save it also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use **background contexts**. I recommend this setup:

```
RootContext (background) for saving --> is parent of
MainContext (main thread) for UI    --> is parent of
WorkerContext (background) for insert, update, delete operations
```

Root context and main context should be set up at app start. You can create a worker context in your web callbacks (when you have the new data available) and then use the context with the block APIs:

```
workerContext.performBlock() {
     // update data here
}
```

When you call `save()` on the worker context, the UI context gets the changes and can update itself gracefully (e.g. via `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`). Make sure you also call save on the root context to persist the data to the persistent store.

This is the basic outline of a good approach. In case you are not familiar with some of the mentioned techniques, you can find good and detailed explanations of many of these on this platform.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried to figure it out, and  re-edit my op, would you take a look? if I go wrong, plz let me know.

Comment: You are assigning the root context as the main context. It should be `mainContext.parentContext` = rootContext`. You missed **parentContext**.

Comment: sorry, that is a typo, I set it right in my project.

Comment: It's all wrong. You are inserting into main context and saving to another context, not using the block API. Please follow my instructions, where it says **create a worker context in the callback**, or  **use the context with the block APIs**, etc.. I cannot keep correcting your code when you are just making random mistakes due to oversight.  - Your question has been answered, so you should accept the answer. Please solve your other technical problems elsewhere, e.g. via other SOF questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert all data in a background thread and save the context when you are done - that will update the context in other threads. Just take care that all saving is done on that background thread to avoid concurrency problems.

Comment: I've tried to store the objects in a global array, and start a timer to call `[_managedObjectContext save:&error]` but tableview shows the data in wrong order. I am really new to core data ,could you plz show me some code?